# Ember js - model not refreshed with new query params

Tags: ember.js

```
// controllers/list.js
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  queryParams: ['page', 'sortBy', {
    refreshModel: true
  }],
  page: 1,
  sortBy: 'createdAt'
});
```

and

```
// templates/components/list-table.hbs
{{#link-to "list" (query-params sortBy="firstName")}}Sort by name{{/link-to}}
```

Why list model is not fully refreshed, when I click "Sort by name" link?
What I'm doing wrong?
Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set refreshModel to queryParams property in routes/list.js file.

You need to set queryParams property in routes/list.js

```
queryParams: { page: { refreshModel: true }, sortBy: { refreshModel: true }}
```

and also define it queryParams property in controllers/list.js

```
queryParams: ['page', 'sortBy']
```